# MySQL select most occurring or average

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table from which I want to select:

1) Either "most occurring" value, if there is any prevailing

2) Or "average" value, if there is no most occurring value.

Example table 1:

```
value
1
2
3
4
```

All values are occurred equally, therefore I want to take `` AVG(`value`) ``

Example table 2:

```
value
1
2
2
3
```

Value `2` prevails, therefore I want to select the value 2.

What mysql query would do this?

Comment: I am unable to do it. I could do it using PHP, I know the idea behind it. Select COUNT(`value`), GROUP BY `value` I get counts. If the biggest count is 1, then SELECT AVG, otherwise select the biggest value.
I don't know MySQL syntax well enough to write this as 1 query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Gordon's answer I tested and corrected the SQL query in SQL Fiddle:

```
SELECT IF(t4.numcnts = 1, t1.avgvalue, t2.topvalue) AS result 
 FROM (select avg(value) as avgvalue from test) t1 
 CROSS JOIN (select value as topvalue from test group by value order by count(*) desc limit 1) t2 
 CROSS JOIN join (select count(distinct cnt) as numcnts from 
    (select count(*) as cnt from test group by value) t3) t4
```

Here is the Fiddle with the two test tables (switch out test2 for test to see the result when a particular value prevails): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76914/3

My changes were to use an `IF` instead of a `CASE`statement in the `SELECT`clause and to add the necessary table aliases for the subselects.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach calculates both values and then chooses between them:

```
select (case when numcnts = 1 then avgvalue else topvalue end)
from (select avg(value)  as avgvalue from t) cross join
     (select value  as topvalue from t group by value order by count(*) desc limit 1) cross join
     (select count(distinct cnt) as numcnts from (select count(*) as cnt from t group by value))
```

Note:  if you have ties for the top, but other values as well, then an arbitrary value is returned.  You don't specify what to do in this case.

Also, the SQL is untested, so it might have syntax errors.